# Sqlite questions regarding Id's

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I have a web app on rails whereby the user submits data that gets stored in the sqlite DB. When the submission page shows it shows the **ID** number of the **DB** which will be that **users ID** for that submission for later reference. Makes sense as it's a ***unique number***.

However Can I get this number to start at say `10000` instead of just `1`.

=========================================

```
def create



@post = Post.new(post_params)
@post.save
redirect_to @post #this is the line that it errors on


end
```

by the way the error i get is ...

```
undefined method `empty?' for 100029:Fixnum
```

Comment: The next number to be assigned is stored in a control table in the database, so you could just change that. Use any sqlite client to inspect the database.  Is your purpose to obscure the id or the number of records you have in the URI ?  You might want to look at this gem... https://github.com/namick/obfuscate_id

Comment: I'll take a look. It's more about having a more usable reference number that looks a bit more practical.

Comment: That Gem looks more like it's random... which might be an option. Ideally I would like the DB submission to say something like 10000,10001,10002.. etc...  It's internal to the business so it doesn't matter about showing visits.

Comment: Ah, wow! It looks like it doesn't like having an integer as the to_param... which I never realised was an issue.  I'll post an alternate solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in your User class... add a new column via migration called "big_id_s" (String)...

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :create_big_id

  def to_param
    big_id_s
  end

  def create_big_id
    self.update_column(:big_id_s, (id + 100000).to_s)
    self
  end 
end
```

In your controllers in the actions when you retrieve a user record (show, edit, update, delete) use this format to retrieve the record...

```
@user = User.find_by_big_id_s(params[:id])
```

Comment: OK I've been away for a couple of days. Just read this and am going to give it a try I'll let you know the results soon.

Comment: ok i think I am going wrong. I have created the big_id integer in the migration file and can see that in the rails console. However does the above code go into the controller or the migration file created?

Comment: each time I submit a new page i look in the console and the big_id field shows nil

Comment: Most of the above code should be in the model record app/models/uer.rb... the line with @user = User.find_by_big_id should be in a method called by your controller show / edit / update / delete  actions.  You could do it as a method or you can insert the line in each of those methods (which is a little less DRY)

Comment: ok i think I'm almost there but not quite. I have a syntax error now from the controller.

Comment: OK I discovered what the last error was and it was too many END's in the post.rb file. So I have deleted that and gained a new error as           


    NoMethodError in PostsController#create

Comment: Hi, yes, I put an "end" in my example code for the class User but presumably you have additional code in the user model.  I'm glad you got the "end" bits fixed.  

The error should tell you what method is missing... it should be mentioned just before the "NoMethodError"... you might want to show your controller code.

Comment: posted the create section of the controller. commented the error line.

Comment: I've revised the answer which should correct the problem you're having.  I've called the new field "bid_id_s" just to distinguish it from the last field...  once you've proven it works, you can delete the "big_id" (integer) field using "remove_column" in a migration, as you don't need it anymore.

Comment: Ok that's it!! brilliant thanks very much for your help, it really is very much appreciated. I am new to ruby, as if you couldn't tell, and this gives me exactly what I need. Thank You!